# Dataset for multi class perceptron

Tags: classification, dataset, multivariable

I am developing a multi-class perceptron algorithm and was wondering if there are any datasets that could be used to test a multi-class perceptron? - A dataset where the classes are linearly separable and have at least 100 or more instances for training?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the good old [iris](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris)? It suits your needs and is good for start.

Comment: i think only one of the classes in the Iris data set is linearly separable. (From the OP's Question, i think he's after data sets w/ *only* linearly separable classes).

Comment: @doug, good point, still I don't think that one can get any non-synthetic fully linearly separable problem. Nevertheless I'll wait for the OP's reaction.

Comment: yes - only one of the classes in the iris data set is linearly separable - so, I've now started experimenting with algorithmically generated datasets.